# Programatically Enable/Disable File Association with macOS App

Tags: macos, file-association

I've set up my macOS app to be able to handle folders that end with the xcasset extension. This isn't pleasing for all users so I would like to make this an optional preference. Is there any way of turning this on and off programatically from within the app, or is there an alternative way of achieving this behaviour?

Here's the plist data I've got setup at the moment.

```
         <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Asset</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <true/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>xcassets</string>
                <string>xcstickers</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
        </dict>
```

Comment: LSRegisterFSRef() seems to be the function you need, but it's deprecated since 10.11 and I couldn't find any information on what exactly we are supposed to use instead.